# ListData.svc not pulling all items from the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, jquery

I  creating a map using Highcharts and jQuery. The data is being pulled form SharePoint. Everything works just fine, except the fact that the list which contains almost every State is bot pulling all of them. This is what I'm using:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MapData?$select=State_abb,County,Indemnity,County_code&$orderby=State asc,County asc&$top=2917
```

I know the list contains 2917 items, I wonder if there is a way to go around the 1000 limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already mentioned in your REST query. You just need to change the value from 2917 to 1000. Make sure to place that as first parameter like below.

```
https://xxxxxxxxxx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MapData?$top=1000&$select=State_abb,County,Indemnity,County_code&$orderby=State asc,County asc
```

It will get only top 1000 records from list.

Comment: Thank you, I actually decided to split the list using three different ajax calls using `top` combined with `skip`. that way none of the call exceeds 1000, and it worked just fine.